# Propagator in external background field

Tags: greens-functions, propagator

This question can be extended to more complicated quadratic actions in a background field, but for simplicity let's just consider the 1D action
$$S=-\frac{1}{2}\int d\tau\, \dot \phi^2 + m^2(\tau)\phi^2$$
Is there a way to write the propagator $\langle\phi(\tau_f)\phi(\tau_i)\rangle$ explicitly (in either momentum or position space)?

I can get an asymptotic expansion for the propagator by treating the $m^2$ term as a perturbation, but I'm looking for something to all orders, however formal it may be.

Comment: Everything depends solely on time (and so on energy), why would you want to get a dependence in space also?

Comment: @DavideMorgante, I mean time and energy when I say "position or momentum space," it's just high-energy language coming through sorry

Comment: Therefore you have a "momentum space" form of the green function. The "position" you can just calculate from the integral by using the residue theorem since the mass term is just a constant when integrating over $\omega$.

Comment: @DavideMorgante, If you can write down an explicit form of the propagator please put it in an answer and I will upvote and accept it if it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I can do better than the following, but if someone else has an alternate approach I'm still interested.

Writing the Lagrangian in momentum space we have
$$\frac{1}{2}\int 
\frac{dp_1 dp_2}{(2\pi)^2}\phi(p_1)\left(p_2^2\delta(p_2-p_1)+m^2(p_2-p_1)\right)\phi(-p_2)$$
The momentum space propagator is just the inverse of this matrix
$$\int dx_1 dx_2 e^{i(x_1 p_1-x_2 p_2)}\langle\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\rangle=\frac{1}{p_2^2}\left(\delta(p_2-p_1)+\frac{m^2(p_2-p_1)}{p_2^2}\right)^{-1}$$
This means the inverse thinking of this as a 'matrix' with momentum indices, and the matrix product involves integrating over the indices. If you expand this as a geometric series you recover the perturbative asymptotic expansion of the propagator.